# Problem with SQL query. Need to distinct my results

Tags: php, mysql

I got table with my conversations, and i need to list alle conversation as topics. So if I'm the sender or the receiver, it should list it as one conversation. So between 2 users, it doesn't matter which role they got.

---

**So if I got:**

```
1, me, mom, "hello mom, I'm good. How are you?", 1, 23/09-2011
2, mom, me, "hello son, how are you?", 1, 22/09-2011
3, me, dad, "hello dad, how are you?", 1, 20/09-2011
```

---

**I want to show it like this:**

```
between You and Mom - Hello mom... - 23/09-2011 - 2 messeges
between You and Dad - Hello dad... - 20/09-2011 - 1 message
```

---

I can't seem to figure out the query. Something with DISTINCT maybe.

I hope you guys can help me out :)

Update

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fisk_beskeder` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `fra` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `til` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dato` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `set` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `besked` text NOT NULL,
  `svar` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

PHP

```
$sql = mysql_query(
    "SELECT `fra`, `til`, `besked`, `dato`, `set`, `id` 
    FROM fisk_beskeder 
    WHERE til = ".$userid." 
       OR fra = ".$userid." 
    ORDER BY id DESC") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Update

Okay, it's working now. Only thing i need is to get the newest data from the group.

```
SELECT count(id), `id`, `fra`, if(a.fra = $cfg_brugerid, a.til, a.fra) AS other, `til`, `besked`, `dato`, `set` 
FROM fisk_beskeder a
WHERE fra = $cfg_brugerid OR til = $cfg_brugerid
GROUP BY other
ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

Comment: Do your *really* need the output as a list of strings rather than just as an ordinary result set? Can't you do the output formatting in PHP?

Comment: You need to show us your table structure. Also, please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: Ill do all the formatting in php. Sorry i didnt say that. I just need data from sql

Comment: It's fairly straightforward to do almost all of what you need by using `GROUP BY MIN(fra, til), MAX(fra, til)`. However it won't be that fast - you will need a slightly different approach if your tables can be large (millions of rows). Is performance an issue?

Comment: Performance is not a big deal here.

Comment: Cant seem to get that GROUP thing to work out. Can you give me the whole query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
SELECT COUNT(msg), msg, a.date,  if(a.from ='me', a.to , a.from) as otherPerson
FROM table a  
WHERE a.from = 'me' or a.to = 'me'
GROUP BY otherPerson
```

Comment: Anyone knows why I get an syntax error, when using if statement in query??

Answer (score 1):

Something like.

```
SELECT COUNT(a.msg), a.msg, a.date 
FROM table a, table b 
WHERE a.from = b.from
AND a.to != b.to
GROUP BY a.from
```

Comment: hmm.. I only got one table with all messages in. Maybe something with group by.